# Losing vertices when i change the style in OpenLayers

Tags: vector, styles, openlayers

I have a vector in a map that I can modify your color in real time with `layer.redraw()` and a color selector. But when I change the color of this vector and activate `modifyFeature`, it loses the vertices, and `Openlayers` just shows me the virtual vertices to drag.

Someone have this problem before?

Comment: Can you post your code in a jsfiddle?